# Issue wtih Radarr when trying to download a file

Tags: .net, download, bittorrent, manjaro

I have been trying to use Radarr for the last few days but I still have issues when I am trying to download a movie. I'm on Manjaro with QBitorrent and Jackett. Here is the log. Can you tell me know what is wrong and what I should do. Thanks a lot.

2023-09-01 14:43:56.6|Fatal|RadarrErrorPipeline|Request Failed. POST /api/v3/movie

[v4.7.5.7809] System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'text')
at NzbDrone.Common.Extensions.PathExtensions.ContainsInvalidPathChars(String text) in ./Radarr.Common/Extensions/PathExtensions.cs:line 175
at NzbDrone.Common.Extensions.PathExtensions.IsPathValid(String path, PathValidationType validationType) in ./Radarr.Common/Extensions/PathExtensions.cs:line 165
at NzbDrone.Core.Validation.Paths.PathValidator.IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext context) in ./Radarr.Core/Validation/Paths/PathValidator.cs:line 29
at FluentValidation.Validators.PropertyValidator.Validate(PropertyValidatorContext context) in C:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\Validators\PropertyValidator.cs:line 80
at FluentValidation.Internal.PropertyRule.InvokePropertyValidator(IValidationContext context, IPropertyValidator validator, String propertyName) in C:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\Internal\PropertyRule.cs:line 519
at FluentValidation.Internal.PropertyRule.Validate(IValidationContext context)+MoveNext() in C:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\Internal\PropertyRule.cs:line 351
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() at FluentValidation.AbstractValidator`1.Validate(ValidationContext`1 context) in C:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\AbstractValidator.cs:line 95 at FluentValidation.AbstractValidator`1.Validate(T instance) in C:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\AbstractValidator.cs:line 62
at Radarr.Http.REST.RestController`1.ValidateResource(TResource resource, Boolean skipValidate, Boolean skipSharedValidate) in ./Radarr.Http/REST/RestController.cs:line 112 at Radarr.Http.REST.RestController`1.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) in ./Radarr.Http/REST/RestController.cs:line 79
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller.OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Radarr.Http.Middleware.BufferingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) in ./Radarr.Http/Middleware/BufferingMiddleware.cs:line 28
at Radarr.Http.Middleware.IfModifiedMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) in ./Radarr.Http/Middleware/IfModifiedMiddleware.cs:line 41
at Radarr.Http.Middleware.CacheHeaderMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) in ./Radarr.Http/Middleware/CacheHeaderMiddleware.cs:line 33
at Radarr.Http.Middleware.StartingUpMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) in ./Radarr.Http/Middleware/StartingUpMiddleware.cs:line 38
at Radarr.Http.Middleware.UrlBaseMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) in ./Radarr.Http/Middleware/UrlBaseMiddleware.cs:line 27
at Radarr.Http.Middleware.VersionMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) in ./Radarr.Http/Middleware/VersionMiddleware.cs:line 29
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)

I was expecting to be able to click on the 'add movie' and see it being downloaded in QBitorrent.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Try using another version. I use radarr's docker container, and switching to the `nightly` tag resolved this issue. As of right now, I didn't face the same issue on version `5.0.2.7997`

`image: lscr.io/linuxserver/radarr:nightly`

Comment: Exact same error ( POST /api/v3/movie Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'text')) and perfectlly solved. Thank you!